# Historical security flaws of popular PHP CMS's?

Tags: php, security, content-management-system, password-protection

I'm creating a PHP CMS, one that I hope will be used by the public. Security is a major concern and I'd like to learn from some of the popular PHP CMS's like Wordpress, Joomla, Drupal, etc. What are some security flaws or vulnerabilities that they have they had in the past that I can avoid in my application and what strategies can I use to avoid them? What are other issues that I need to be concerned with that they perhaps didn't face as a vulnerability because they handled it correctly from the start? What additional security features or measures would you include, anything from minute details to system level security approaches? ***Please be as specific as possible.*** I'm generally aware of most of the usual attack vectors, but I want to make sure that all the bases are covered, so don't be afraid to mention the obvious as well. Assume PHP 5.2+.

**Edit**: I'm changing this to a community wiki. Even though Arkh's excellent answer is accepted, I'm still interested in further examples if you have them.

Comment: +1 great question, something special for everybody to know :)

Comment: Aren't there enough php cms's out there?

Comment: should be community wiki?

Comment: @Byron - I thought someone might say something along those lines. To answer, none of the popular ones met my needs for the way I wanted to work as a developer. I also felt as if the admin user interface could be made easier for the end user. Time will tell if others feel the same. ;-)

Comment: I wonder why everyone jump to upvote such a useless question. It has nothing to do with security. One cannot learn security from someone's silly mistakes. Security must be a system, not a few patches.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel - Feel free to suggest system level security approaches as well. As I'm creating the CMS, everything from architecture to minute details is fair game in the way of suggestions.

Comment: that would be offtopic to this question

Comment: Sounds ontopic to me. Lots of people might overlook simple things such as checking every input for not only SQL injection but JS injection.

Comment: SQL injection is a myth. there is no injection over **syntactically correct** data. Go figure. While XSS injection protection must be a system again, based on the deep knowledge, not on funny tales which the OP seems to gather.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Things a programmer should know before building a website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861428/things-a-programmer-should-know-before-building-a-website)

Comment: @George - While the question that that question is referring to is very helpful, it's more generalized. This one is focused specifically on security, with the added request for historical examples of security in other PHP CMS's.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel - The question has been edited to make system level security more on topic. Again, your specific suggestions would be valued.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

### Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF)

#### Description :

The basic idea is to trick a user to a page where his browser will initiate a POST or GET request to the CMS you attack.

Imagine you know the email of a CMS powered site administrator. Email him some funny webpage with whatever you want in it. In this page, you craft a form with the data used by the admin panel of the CMS to create a new admin user. Send those data to the website admin panel, with the result in a hidden iframe of your webpage.
Voilà, you got your own administrator account made.

#### How to prevent it :

The usual way is to generate random short-lived (15mn to hour) nonce in all your forms. When your CMS receive a form data, it checks first if the nonce is alright. If not, the data is not used.

#### CMS examples :

- [CMS made simple](http://www.secuobs.com/secumail/btsecumail/msg19456.shtml)
- [Joomla!](http://developer.joomla.org/security/news/293-20090301-core-multiple-xsscsrf.html)
- [Drupal](http://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2008-1981/20081981-vulnerable-softwares-references-exploits.html)
- [ModX](http://heine.familiedeelstra.com/modx-csrf-woes-arbitrary-code-execution)

#### More information :

On the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) page and on the [OWASP project](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29).

### Bad password storing

#### Description :

Imagine your database get hacked and published on something like wikileak. Knowing that a big part of your users use the same login and password for a lot of websites, do you want them to be easy to get ?

No. You need to mitigate the damages done if your database datas become public.

#### How to prevent it :

- A first idea is to hash them. Which is a bad idea because of [rainbow tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) (even if the hash is not md5 but sha512 for example).
- Second idea : add a unique random salt before hashing so the hackers has to bruteforce each password. The problem is, the hacker can compute a lot of hash fast.
- So, the current idea is to make it slow to hash the passwords : you don't care because you don't do it often. But the attacker will cry when he gets from 1000 hash generated per ms to 1.

To ease the process, you can use the library [phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) developped by some password guru.

#### CMS examples :

- Joomla! : salted md5
- ModX : md5
- Typo3 : [cleartext](http://bugs.typo3.org/view.php?id=10873&nbn=5)
- Drupal : switched to phpass after [this discussion](http://drupal.org/node/29706#comment-342450).

#### More information :

The [phpass page](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/).

### Cross Site Scripting (XSS)

#### Description

The goal of these attacks, is to make your website display some script which will be executed by your legitimate user.

You have two kind of these : persistent or not. The first one comes usually from something your user can save, the other count on parameters given by a request sent. Here is an example, not persistent :

```
<?php
if(!is_numeric($_GET['id'])){
  die('The id ('.$_GET['id'].') is not valid');
}
?>
```

Now your attacker can just send links like `http://www.example.com/vulnerable.php?id=<script>alert('XSS')</script>`

#### How to prevent it

You need to filter everything you output to the client. The easiest way is to use [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) if you don't want to let your user save any html. But, when you let them output html (either their own html or some generated from other things like bbcode) you have to be very careful. Here is an old example using the "onerror" event of the img tag : [vBulletin vulnerability](http://www.securityfocus.com/archive/1/511047). Or you have the old [Myspace's Samy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samy_%28XSS%29).

#### CMS examples :

- [CMS made simple](http://www.securityfocus.com/archive/1/511178)
- [Mura CMS](http://www.getmura.com/index.cfm/blog/mura-cms-xss-vulnerability-fix/)
- [Drupal](http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2009/Mar/115)
- [ModX](http://modxcms.com/forums/index.php/topic,47759.0.html)

#### More information :

You can check [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) and [OWASP](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29). You also have a lot of XSS vector on [ha.ckers](http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html) page.

### Mail header injection

#### Description :

Mail headers are separated by the CRLF (`\r\n`) sequence. When you use some user data to send mails (like using it for the From: or To:) they can inject more headers. With this, they can send anonymous mails from your server.

#### How to prevent it :

Filter all the `\n`, `\r`, `%0a` and `%0d` characters in your headers.

#### CMS examples :

- [Jetbox CMS](http://www.mail-archive.com/bugtraq@securityfocus.com/msg22509.html)

#### More information :

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-mail_injection) is a good start as usual.

### SQL Injection

#### Description :

The old classic. It happen when you form a SQL query using direct user input. If this input is crafted like needed, a user can do exactly what he want.

#### How to prevent it :

Simple. Don't form SQL queries with user input. Use [parameterized queries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametrized_query#Parameterized_statements).
Consider any input which is not coded by yourself as user input, be it coming from the filesystem, your own database or a webservice for example.

#### CMS example :

- [Drupal](http://drupal.org/node/65357)
- [Joomla!](http://secunia.com/advisories/20874)
- [ModX](http://secunia.com/Advisories/33405/)
- [Pars CMS](http://www.securityfocus.com/archive/1/510066)

#### More information :

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and [OWASP](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) have really good pages on the subject.

### Http response splitting

#### Description :

Like e-mail headers, the http headers are separated by the CLRF sequence. If your application uses user input to output headers, they can use this to craft their own.

#### How to prevent it :

Like for emails, filter `\n`, `\r`, `%0a` and `%0d` characters from user input before using it as part of a header. You can also [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) your headers.

#### CMS examples :

- [Drake CMS](http://www.securityfocus.com/bid/23851/discuss)
- [Plone CMS](http://plone.org/products/cachefu/issues/88)
- [Wordpress](http://www.securiteam.com/unixfocus/6X00B0ABFE.html)

#### More information :

I'll let you guess a little as to where you can find a lot of infos about this kind of attack. [OWASP](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTP_Response_Splitting) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_response_splitting).

### Session hijacking

#### Description :

In this one, the attacker want to use the session of another legitimate (and hopefully authenticated) user.
For this, he can either change his own session cookie to match the victim's one or he can make the victim use his (the attacker's) own session id.

#### How to prevent it :

Nothing can be perfect here :
 - if the attacker steal the victim's cookie, you can check that the user session matches the user IP. But this can render your site useless if legitimate users use some proxy which change IP often.
 - if the attacker makes the user use his own session ID, just use [session_regenerate_id](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.session-regenerate-id.php) to change the session ID of a user when his rights change (login, logout, get in admin part of the website etc.).

#### CMS examples :

- [Joomla!](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=1522329) and [Drupal](http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2008/Sep/414)
- [Zen Cart](http://securityreason.com/securityalert/2866)

#### More information :

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking) page on the subject.

### Other

- User DoSing : if you prevent bruteforcing of login attempt by disabling the usernames tried and not the IP the attempts come from, anyone can block all your users in 2mn. Same thing when generating new passwords : don't disable the old one until the user confirm the new one (by loging with it for example).
- Using user input to do something on your filesystem. Filter this like if it was cancer mixed with aids. This concern the use of include and require on files which path is made in part from the user input.
- Using [eval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php), [system](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php), [exec](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) or anything from this kind with user input.
- Don't put files you don't want web accessible in web accessible directory.

You have a lot of things you can read on the [OWASP](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:Attack) page.

Comment: Bumping this a little so more people can enhance it.

Comment: Ironically, your Cross-site scripting example is vulnerable to cross-site scripting. ;)

Comment: Oh, yeah. Sorry, I did not read it, I just quickly scrolled down and thought it was not supposed to be vulnerable to XSS. :)

Comment: Session hijacking - you mention ip checks but not user agent. If you match the user agent string to the session, you will of course get matches, however it does add a little extra layer of security.

Answer (score 12):

I remember a rather funny one from phpBB. The autologin cookie contained a serialized array containing a userId and encrypted password (no salt). Change the password to a boolean with value true and you could log in as anyone you wanted to be. Don't you love weaktyped languages?

Another issue that phpBB had was in an regular expression for the highlighting of search keywords that had a callback (with the `e modifier`), which enabled you to execute your own PHP code - for example, system calls on unsecure systems or just output the config file to get the MySQL login/password.

So to sum this story up:

- Watch out for PHP being weaktyped ( `md5( "secretpass" ) == true` ).
- Be careful with all code that could be used in a callback (or worse, eval).

And of course there are the other issues already mentioned before me.

Answer (score 3):

Another application level security issue that I've seen CMSes deal with is insufficiently authorizing page or function level access. In other words, security being set by only showing links when you are authorized to view those links, but not fully checking that the user account is authorized to view the page or use the functionality once they are on the page.

In other words, an admin account has links displayed to go to user management pages. But the user management page only checks that the user is logged in, not that they are logged in and admin. A regular user then logs in, manually types in the admin page URI, then has full admin access to the user management pages and makes their account into an admin account.

You'd be surprised how many times I've seen things like that even in shopping cart applications where user CC data is viewable.

Answer (score 3):

So so many..

A number of answers here are listing specific vuls they remember or generic "things i worry about when writing a webapp", but if you want a reasonably reliable list of a majority of reported vulnerabilities found historically, then you wouldn't do much worse than to search the [National Vulnerability Database](http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/search?cid=1)

There are 582 vulnerabilities reported in Joomla or Joomla addons, 199 for Wordpress and 345 for Drupal for you to digest.

For generic understanding of common webapp vuls, the [OWASP Top Ten project](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project) has recently been updated and is an essential read for any web developer.

- A1: Injection
- A2: Cross-Site Scripting (XSS)
- A3: Broken Authentication and Session Management
- A4: Insecure Direct Object References
- A5: Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF)
- A6: Security Misconfiguration
- A7: Insecure Cryptographic Storage
- A8: Failure to Restrict URL Access
- A9: Insufficient Transport Layer Protection
- A10: Unvalidated Redirects and Forwards

Answer (score 3):

The biggest one that so many people seem to either forget or not realise is that anyone can post any data to your scripts, including cookies and sessions etc. And don't forget, just because a user is logged in, doesn't mean they can do any action.

For example, if you had a script that handles the adding/editing of a comment, you might have this:

```
if ( userIsLoggedIn() ) {
    saveComment( $_POST['commentid'], $_POST['commenttext'] )
}
```

Can you see what's wrong? You checked that the user is logged in, but you didn't check if the user owns the comment, or is able to edit the comment. Which means any logged-in user could post a comment ID and content and edit others' comments!

---

Another thing to remember when providing software to others is that server set ups vary wildly. When data is posted you may want to do this, for example:

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    $var = stripslashes($_POST['var']);
else
    $var = $_POST['var'];
```

Answer (score 2):

Four big ones in my mind:

- using exec on untrusted data/code (or in general)
- include-ing files from remote URL's for local execution
- enabling register globals so that get and post variables 
  get variable values automatically assigned.
- not escaping db entered data/ allowing SQL injection attacks 
  (usually happens when not using a DB API layer)

Answer (score 1):

Disallow POST from other domain/IP So Bots cant login/submit forms.

Comment: He can't, just because it's stupid. Even if he meant to check a referer, it wont stop any bot.

Comment: Okay 
can be implemented various ways .One easy (but loose way) i am writing down below.

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']==[ur site URL])
 // ALow it is safe
else
 //Dont allow

But sadly the HTTP_REFERER can be faked easily , So better use some encrypted hidden value with each form and then check validate it when get posted .To achieve that must implement something client side (JS).

Comment: a bot will forge the referer if need be.   howver csrf is a different story.

Comment: encrypted hidden value can be sent back as well

Comment: if you have a Bot backed by a real browser then yes , Normal bots Can't.And i think most scrapping bots are no way backed by browsers/Js engine so they can't really catch what being done Via client side.

Comment: R u talking of JS encrypted fields? That will hit fair users. Ever used some of a kind in real? And you had gone too far from your answer.

Comment: " So better use some encrypted hidden value with each form and then check validate it when get poste " i meant it to be added via JS on page load or some Submit button click.

Comment: Cross-site request forgery (CSRF) protection is a very very good idea. Read more at OWASP: http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Answer (score 0):

**People**, the biggest security breech, is the **human** **stupidity**. *Trust*, *review* code. You need a special team, which will review anything that added as an extra code in your application, cms's problem are the outsource, the incomings, WordPress, Drupal, Joomla, and other popular cms, like default installations, they are really in a very good point secure. The problem is coming when you leave people to add extra code in your application, without a good review (or better, without penetration testing). This is the point where WordPress and Joomla have the weakness, there re so many plugin n theme devs, there are so many approvals,hundreds of outdated plugins n themes outhere.... So imho, if you are able to build a strong team, a good security plan, train your contributors, and learn them how to code secure, and with all the other comments before mine, then you will be able to move on and say :ei hi that's my cms, and it's a bit more secure than all the other cms on the net ;)

Answer (score -2):

Here's a potential pitfall for forum admins especially, but also anyone who codes up a form with a dropdown selector but doesn't validate that the posted response was actually one of the available options.

In college, I realized that the user's 'country' selector in phpBB had no such validation.

In our school forum, Instead of 'United States' or 'Afganistan', my country could be ANYTHING, no matter how silly, or filthy.  All I needed was an html POST form.  It took my classmates a few days to figure out how I had done it, but soon, all the 'cool kids' had funny phrases instead of countries displayed under their usernames.

Going to a geek college was awesome. :D