# How can I test PHP site security for most common security flaws?

Tags: php, security

I need to make sure that PHP sites that I administrate, don't have any common PHP flaws, like SQL injection, wrongly configured permissions to files and folders etc. By site I mean for example Joomla site with plugins and modules. Making this security check manually can be time consuming and automated test could be run on daily basis to just make sure nothing has changed.

So my question is that is there any good automated software for this or do I have to code one myself?

Comment: Would be nice to have a script to test common security flaws

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using a fuzzer is a good idea. But, you could also try coding an automated system yourself, as this will boost your knowledge about php and security issues/loop holes in your php sites.

I would personally use Google's [Skipfish](http://code.google.com/p/skipfish/) and find out for yourself if there are problems, then build your own just for your needs and ease of use. Good luck!

Comment: The link to Skipfish is dead now, according to their [downloads page](https://code.google.com/archive/p/skipfish/downloads) the last (beta..) version seems to be 2.10 dated 2012.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done with a [fuzzer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzz_testing) or a [web vulnerability scanner](http://sectools.org/web-scanners.html).

Answer (score 4):

I've been using netsparker http://www.mavitunasecurity.com/

Not exactly what you need but it can help a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

You should do both. Review your code and look for possible SQL-Injections etc.

Google released a very nice tool named "[Skipfish](http://code.google.com/p/skipfish/)" that scans your application for common security holes / attack patterns.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the open source project [wapiti](http://wapiti.sourceforge.net/) which will test for XSS, SQLi,  LFI/RFI and many more.  There is also the commercial product [Sitewatch](https://sitewat.ch/en/About)($),  and the best is [NTOSpider](http://www.ntobjectives.com/)($$$$$).

Answer (score 1):

To familiarize yourself with common web security flaws, you may also wish to explore [Webgoat](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_WebGoat_Project)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a static code analysis tool, e.g. [RIPS](https://www.ripstech.com) for PHP, to analyze your complete source code for security flaws. Fuzzing your website from the outside may not cover all code paths and overlook issues.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there's anything -good (so, 100% reliable)- that's automated. But a nice topic to go through might be this one on SO, as it lists "historical security flaws".

[Historical security flaws of popular PHP CMS's?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951917/historical-security-flaws-of-popular-php-cmss/)

Answer (score 0):

RFI, LFI, SQL Injection, too many to discuss, and probably too boring to read one by one. I suggest you use a fuzzer instead. There many free ones and here's a wiki article about it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzz_testing

Answer (score 0):

This is a new and good tool fot testing,it can be used, from web developers, penetration testers or even security researchers to test web applications with the view to find bugs, errors or vulnerabilities. It worths to give a try 
[Commix](https://github.com/stasinopoulos/commix)