# PHP Hacking and Security

Tags: php, security

What are the possible security holes that exist in PHP programing. Weak PHP programming.

Comment: I think you should Google the subject and then ask a more specific question here if you still have one.

Comment: You might want to check out this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115559/exploitable-php-functions/3697776#3697776 and read the owasp top 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary response you will get is SQL injection from input not properly sanitized. Another possibility I can think of offhand is allowing scripts to be uploaded and subsequently executed. OReilly has a book on the topic also, oreilly.com/catalog/9780596006563, Essential PHP Security. Also check out the PHP security guide -

http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this:
[Historical security flaws of popular PHP CMS's?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951917/historical-security-flaws-of-popular-php-cmss/)